# Which repositories of mine are archived in the Arctic by GitHub?

Tags: github

It's probably not the right place to ask this question but when I mouse hover my **[Arctic Code Vault Contributor](https://archiveprogram.github.com/)** icon on my Github profile page, I saw something like this:

> ... contributed code to several repositories in the 2020 GitHub Archive Program: x, y, z and more!

How do I know what exactly are those repositories archived except the x, y and z shown here? What's the criteria for archiving the repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arctic Code Vault includes repositories with :

- Any commits between the announcement at Universe on November 13, 2019, and February 2, 2020
- At least one star and any commits from the year before the snapshot
  between February 3, 2019, and February 2, 2020
- At least 250 stars, regardless of when their most recent activity
  occurred

Source : [Github Blog](https://github.blog/2020-02-03-the-arctic-code-vault-starts-production-and-your-open-source-projects-are-being-archived/)

Comment: maybe someone will see this some day and have the inspiration to write a script to parse a user's github and output the repos that match the requirements